# some portion of screen not catching gestures (i.e swipes,scroll,tap...)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

some portions of the screen is not working 
(tested on 2 real devices and an emulator)

there's no hidden widgets that might catch the gestures silently

i don't even know what to search for now :\

checked my code but haven't done any wierd custom thing and all widgets are OEM widgets

[illustrated the app here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYnoD.png)

any ideas ?

this is the widget that contains all buttons and widgets that are having the issue :

```
ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0),
    controller: _scrollController,
    itemCount: 1,
    scrollDirection: displayWidth > 600 ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListBody(
          mainAxis: displayWidth > 600 ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0),
            ),
            content_firstCard(displayWidth, displayHeight), // explanation
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  0.0,
                  0.0,
                  displayWidth > 600 ? 20.0 : 0.0,
                  displayWidth > 600 ? 0.0 : 20.0),
            ),
            content_secondCard2(displayWidth, displayHeight), // flutter
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  0.0,
                  0.0,
                  displayWidth > 600 ? 20.0 : 0.0,
                  displayWidth > 600 ? 0.0 : 20.0),
            ),
            content_thirdCard(displayWidth, displayHeight),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  0.0,
                  0.0,
                  displayWidth > 600 ? 20.0 : 0.0,
                  displayWidth > 600 ? 0.0 : 20.0),
            ),
            content_forthCard(displayWidth, displayHeight),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  0.0,
                  0.0,
                  displayWidth > 600 ? 20.0 : 0.0,
                  displayWidth > 600 ? 0.0 : 20.0),
            ),
          ]);
    });
```

Comment: try `debugPrintGestureArenaDiagnostics` and/or `debugPrintRecognizerCallbacksTrace` - maybe those will tell you something about your lost gestures

Comment: @pskink tried "debugPrintGestureArenaDiagnostics" now , the portion that wasn't catching gestures are not even firing those "gesture arena" logs

Comment: you tried those two set to `true`?

Comment: @pskink yes both are set to true , and are working for other portions of the screen

Comment: @pskink :D yes they are , tried the app on 2 real devices and an emulator to be sure i'm not missing sth stupidly simple :D

Comment: try just for testing add only one widget: `Listener` and add `prints` for `onPointerDown: print` and `onPointerMove: print`

Comment: @pskink tried Listener but didn't really show press or move events on Press and moves :\ , only fired when animated the ListView

, but tested on another device and it seems that widgets are not getting clicked but this showed in console : 
ViewRootImpl(21113): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Comment: wait, `Listener` does not show anything? even on top half? hmmm, did you add any child to it? if no try adding some simple `Container` - give it a `height`, `width` and `color` to be sure it really shows up

Comment: @pskink right , I did that already 
I removed the listView
like this :


`Listener(`
         `onPointerDown: myPrint('onPointerDown'),`
         `onPointerMove: myPrint('onPointerMove'),`
         `onPointerUp: myPrint('onPointerUp'),`
         `child: Container(`
          `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9,`
           `height: 1500,`
           `color: Colors.red,`
           `child: Container(),`

Comment: and nothing? onPointerDown / onPointerMove not called at all?

Comment: @pskink yup , nothing , I animated the widget at some point , and That fired all listeners at once

Comment: try `void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Listener(onPointerMove: print, child: Container(color: Colors.red))));
}` - do you see red screen? if so make any gesture and watch the logs

Comment: @pskink tried that , prints are there now , so then again tried the first Listener but with `print` instead of `myPrint` , it worked for other portions but again not for the bottom half , is there any ways I could see all the widgets (hidden or not) with outlines or sth live on the device ?

Comment: [devtools](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview) shows them - but with the code i gave you, do you see all the events?

Comment: @pskink it was stupidly simple then , There Was A Hidden Text Somewhere I Forgot About , :hearts thank you :hearts

Comment: sure, your welcome, you found it with devtools?

Comment: @pskink Yes :hearts
, you can answer the question if you want
to be accepted
if not , I'll accept my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a hidden text catching gestures

tried **devTools** to find it

opened devTools > clicked on device screen after devTools opened > clicked search button on the bottom left of the screen > clicked the portoin of the screen that wasn't catching the gestures > damn widget showed on devtool's WidgetTree :D

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGeZH.png)